# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError actionListeners

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I'm new into Java... and I've got this idea of building a scientific calculator and after I implemented some of the `actionListeners` I've got the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at java.awt.Insets.(Insets.java:103)
>       at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.getScreenInsets(Native Method)
>       at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.getScreenInsets(WToolkit.java:567)
>       at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:498)
>       at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536)
>       at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)
>       at javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:224)
>       at GUI.(GUI.java:29)
>       at actionListeners.(actionListeners.java:9)
>       at GUI.(GUI.java:9)
>       at actionListeners.(actionListeners.java:9)
>       at GUI.(GUI.java:9)
>       at actionListeners.(actionListeners.java:9)
>       at GUI.(GUI.java:9)
>       at actionListeners.(actionListeners.java:9)
>       at GUI.(GUI.java:9)
>       at actionListeners.(actionListeners.java:9)

```
and this error keeps showing alot . What could be the problem ?
```

Here is the code

```
public GUI() {
    super("Calculator");
    setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));

    result = new JTextArea();
    result.setEditable(false);
    add(result);
    divide.addActionListener(actionListeners);
    add(divide);
    multiply.addActionListener(actionListeners);
    add(multiply);
    substract.addActionListener(actionListeners);
    add(substract);
    sum.addActionListener(actionListeners);
    add(sum);
    for(int i=0;i<=numberButtons.length-1;i++)
 {
     numberButtons[i]= new JButton(Integer.toString(i));}

    add(numberButtons[7]);
    add(numberButtons[8]);
    add(numberButtons[9]);
    add(C);
    add(CE);
    add(numberButtons[4]);
    add(numberButtons[5]);
    add(numberButtons[6]);
    add(sqrt);
    add(cubic);
    add(numberButtons[1]);
    add(numberButtons[2]);
    add(numberButtons[3]);
    add(percentage);
    add(divideByOne);
    add(numberButtons[0]);
    add(point);
    add(square);
    add(OK);

}
public void setTextResult(String a) {
    result.setText(a);
  }
}
```

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.naming.spi.DirStateFactory.Result;

public class actionListeners implements ActionListener {

Functions fn = new Functions();
GUI go = new GUI();


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String x = e.getActionCommand();
    switch (x) {
    case "/":
        fn.divide(fn.getA(), fn.getB());
        go.setTextResult(Double.toString(fn.getResult()));
        break;
    case "*":
        fn.multiply(fn.getA(), fn.getB());
        break;
    case "-":
        fn.substract(fn.getA(), fn.getB());
        break;
    case "+":
        fn.sum(fn.getA(), fn.getB());
        break;
    case "+-":
        fn.divide(fn.getA(), fn.getB());
        break;
    case "C":
        go.setTextResult(" ");
        break;
    case "CE":
        go.setTextResult(" ");
        fn.setResult(0);
        break;
    case "sqrt":
        fn.sqrt(fn.getA());
        break;
    case "OK":
        go.setTextResult(Double.toString(fn.getResult()));
        break;
    case "SQRT":
        break;
    case "%":
        break;
    case "x^2":
        break;
    case "x^3":
        break;
    case "1/x":
        break;
    default:
        go.setTextResult("Eroare");
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific about where exactly the error accour?

Comment: when I try to run the code, I've posted the log from Console. PS: forgot to add the Functions class, but I don't think that could be the problem.

Comment: StackOverflow usually means that you have a recursive function call that does not stop. Apparently there is one at rule 9...

Comment: @ Haneev... yes I've read that it's related to some kind of a recursive function, but I can't see the problem in my case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a stack overflow error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent presented your complete code but you appear to have a cyclic dependency between the  `GUI` and `actionListeners` classes. Each one requires the other to be instantiated resulting in the stacktrace as shown. Just create the required instance of `actionListeners` in `GUI` but not the other way around.

Suggestion:

- Consider using an [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for shared functionality between buttons

Comment: I understand, the rest of the code is a bunch of functions for the math operations, I don't think the problem is there. Anyway I understand what you said, but then how I get my answer writen in the JTextArea? I need an object of GUI into the actionListeners for that.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Read [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 0):

first of all what is your java version you are using strings in switch statement.It is implemented in java 7 and in your code addActionListener(actionListeners) you have to pass the object of ActionListener object.check those two..